# Google Map API V3 for Android browser the Marker is not centered on map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with my marker on google map, it does not appear on center of the map, instead it always appear on upper left of the map.

Here is my code. Thanks for replies!

function initialize() {
        getCurrentLocation();

```
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    currentLocationGPS = new google.maps.LatLng(latPos,longPos);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: currentLocationGPS,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currentLocationGPS, 
        map: map,
        draggable:true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(
        marker,
        'drag',
        function() {
            latPos = marker.position.lat();
            latLong = marker.position.lng();
        }
    );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to set your marker on the position desired:

```
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```

Comment: i used it but it still the same.

Comment: Have you tried it on different browsers in android? Is this same map available not on a mobile phone?

Comment: Is this with jqtouch?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>

that's what i used on my page.